# How to obtain primal problem from Lagrangian?

Tags: convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, duality-theorems

If you're trying to optimize $\min_x f_0(x)$ subject to $f_i(x) \leq 0$ then the Lagrangian would be

$$L(x, \lambda) = f_0(x) + \sum_i \lambda_i f_i(x)$$

The dual problem is $\max_\lambda g(y)$ where $g(\lambda)$ is obtained from the Lagrangian above:

$$g(\lambda) = \min_{x} \mathcal{L}(x, \lambda)$$

Now my question is, how do I obtain *the primal problem itself* from the Lagrangian?

I think the primal is $\min_x f(x)$ where

$$f(x) = \max_{\lambda} \mathcal{L}(x, \lambda)$$

but is this correct?

Oddly enough, I've never seen this mentioned anywhere, so I feel I might be missing something.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but $f_0(x) = L(x,0)$ and $f_k(x) = L(x,e_k)-L(x,0)$.

Comment: @copper.hat: That doesn't make any sense, your $f_k$ is a function of $e_k$ but you haven't written it as a parameter of it.

Comment: It does make sense. $L(x,e_k) = f_0(x) + f_k(x)$ just from the formula above. In addition, $L(x,0) = f_0(x)$, so subtracting gives $f_k(x) = L(x,e_k)-L(x,0)$. What part does not make sense to you?

Comment: Perhaps I am missing your point, the primal problem arises directly from the Lagrangian as in $\inf_x \sup_{ \lambda \ge 0} L(x, \lambda)$. The dual problem switches the $\inf $ and $\sup$ to get $\sup_{ \lambda \ge 0} \inf_x L(x, \lambda)$.

Comment: @copper.hat: Don't worry about it, I got my answer, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the primal optimal value is $\inf_x \sup_{\lambda \geq 0} L(x,\lambda)$ and the dual optimal value is $\sup_{\lambda \geq 0} \inf_x L(x,\lambda)$.  A primal and dual optimal pair of variables gives you a saddle point of the Lagrangian.  This is discussed on p. 238 (section 5.4.1) of Boyd and Vandenberghe, and is also discussed in other convex optimization books such as Borwein and Lewis (p. 88, section 4.3).

Comment: +1 thanks for mentioning the saddle point! That's a good intuition.

Comment: Duality considerably predates Boyd et al. I think von Neumann is credited with the min-max interpretation.

Comment: @copper.hat yes, good point, I mentioned Boyd and Vandenberghe mainly because it's one of the most popular convex optimization textbooks right now.